# How does photoswipe apply styles to blur image when you click on share button?

Tags: javascript, css, photoswipe

You can see example here: http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/gbadPv
Click on Share button and you'll see it blurs the image (and everything else).

I am observing this in inspector and I can't figure it out.

I have downloaded source code and it set a watch in `photoswipe-ui-defaults.js` in this last line:

```
    _openWindowPopup = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

        pswp.shout('shareLinkClick', e, target);
```

It never gets executed.

I have added other similar modal and I want to achieve same effect, but I can't figure out what is being done to achieve that blur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it would looks partly complicated that's why it isn't clear for the first look.

There all time rendered `.pswp_share-modal` with this *css*

**Share Modal:**

```
.pswp_share-modal {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1600;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    will-change: opacity;
}
```

When you click to the "share" button somewhere in js `.pswp__share-modal--fade-in` class attaches to the same element with this *css*:

**Modal with fade in effect:**

```
.pswp__share-modal--fade-in {
    opacity: 1
}
```

As you can see the general idea is to turn opacity to 100% when share modal is active. Blur effect is exist cause actual modal background has `rgba(0,0,0,0.5);`

Comment: Oh I see share modal is actually stretched over entire screen. I thought it was going to be only the modal dialog part.

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš Yup, it's stretched

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is add an extra div, make it full screen, and then add a background to the div. I have an example here (it looks ugly but you'll catch what I'm trying to say).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#modal-btn').click(function(){
    $('.modal').css("display","block");
  });

  $('.modal').click(function(){
    $(this).css("display","none");
  });

});
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
 }
  
 .modal {
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: none;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 2;
 }
 
 .modal-content {
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <!-- Page content -->
  <div>
    The content that goes in the background.
    <button id="modal-btn" class="btn">Open Modal</button>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">The Modal Content</div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```